# how can I get First() on Task<List<...>>?

Tags: c#

If I have

```
Task<List<SomeTable>> models = _dbContext.SomeTable.ToListAsync();
```

How can I now use First() ?

```
models.First() // Task<List<..>> does not contain a definition for First
```

Comment: You cannot use `First` because you don't have the result of the task yet

Comment: Either `await` this task and get result or use `ToList()` to make is synchronously.

Answer (score 4):

You would need to `await` the result of async method `ToListAsync()` to get `List<T>` back as async methods always returns `Task` or `Task<TResult>`:

```
List<SomeTable> models = await _dbContext.SomeTable.ToListAsync();
```

and the method in which you are calling it will also need to be `async` for this.

Or alternatively block the async call [but that's not recommended approach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx):

```
List<SomeTable> models = _dbContext.SomeTable.ToListAsync().Result;
```

Now you can get the first item using `FirstOrDefault()` as `First()` would fail at run-time if there is no item returned in the collection:

```
var model = models.FirstOrDefault();
```

Now as soon as the Db call completes and materializes your result in to in memory collection will get stores in `models`.

Comment: @mason if the calling method is not async declared then we might want to block the async call, mentioned that